# AWS Route53 Resource: Record Set- Target Alias Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, recordset

Trying to deploy a CFT that contains a Route53::RecordSet Resource. This is the error I get.

> Tried to create an alias that targets \052., type A in zone
>   Z1UJRXOUMOOFQ8, but the alias target name does not lie within the
>   target zone

This is my CFT template for my Record Set Resource

```
DnsGateway:
    Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSet
    Properties:
      Comment: DNS for custom domain endpoint
      HostedZoneId:
        Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "dns-${Environment}-HostedZoneId"
      AliasTarget:
        DNSName: 
          !Ref RegionalDomainName 
        HostedZoneId: 
          !FindInMap [ RegionMap, !Ref "AWS::Region", HostedZoneId ]
        EvaluateTargetHealth: true
      Name: 
        Fn::Join:
          - "."
          - - Example
            - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "dns-${Environment}-SubZoneDomain"
      Type: A
      Region: !Ref AWS::Region
      SetIdentifier: !Sub "Example-API-RS-${Environment}-${AWS::Region}"
```

Comment: Minor Formatting

Answer (score 1):

You receive this error when your aliasTarget is missconfigured, here I can see that your DNSName and HostedZoneId has wrong value:

You can find these value needed in attributes of your custom domain.

Assuming your `RegionalDomainName`  is a ressource of type `AWS::ApiGateway::DomainName`

you can configure your alias target using attributes of `RegionalDomainName` like this :

```
  AliasTarget:
    DNSName: 
      Fn::GetAtt: [ RegionalDomainName, RegionalDomainName] 
    HostedZoneId: 
      Fn::GetAtt: [ RegionalDomainName, RegionalHostedZoneId]
    EvaluateTargetHealth: true
```

PS: Use `Ref` on `RegionalDomainName` give the domain name you configure wich is not the same as the regional domain name provided by AWS